# click не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Отображаются звездочки рейтинга пользователя, при наведении курсора содержимое блока с id edit_user_rating меняется на пустые звездочки с class span_rating. При клике на звездочку берется data rating и дальше будет обрабатываться.

А если курсор убрать из блока содержимое блока вернется (звездочки с рейтингом)

Если курсор завести сверху то click не работает

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <style>  
  #edit_user_rating {
   text-align: center;
   width: 200px;
   background: #000;
   height: 50px;
  }
  
  .rating_star {
   unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
   direction: rtl;
   transition: 0.2s;
   color: #737373;
  }
  .rating_star > span {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   font-size: 25px;
   height: 0.1px;
   transition: 0.2s;
   
  }
  .rating_star > span:hover:before,
  .rating_star > span:hover ~ span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
   color: #FEDF69;
   transition: 0.2s;
  }

  .star_select {
   color: #FEDF69!important;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="edit_user_rating">
  <div class="rating_star">
   <span>&#9734;</span><span>&#9734;</span><span>&#9734;</span><span class="star_select">&#9733;</span><span class="star_select">&#9733;</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <script>
  $("body").on("mouseenter", "#edit_user_rating", function(){
   $("#edit_user_rating").html('<div class="rating_star"><span class="click" data-id="5">&#9734;</span><span class="click" data-id="4">&#9734;</span><span class="click" data-id="3">&#9734;</span><span class="click" data-id="2">&#9734;</span><span class="click" data-id="1">&#9734;</span></div>');
  });
  
  $("body").on("mouseleave", "#edit_user_rating", function(){
   $("#edit_user_rating").html('<div class="rating_star"><span>&#9734;</span><span>&#9734;</span><span>&#9734;</span><span class="star_select">&#9733;</span><span class="star_select">&#9733;</span></div>');
  });
  
  $("body").on("click", ".click", function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   var id = $(this).data('id');
   alert(id);
  });
 </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А можете сделать ваш код запускаемым?

Comment: Что и куда вы хотите запускать? Вопрос: Есть блок, при наведении курсора на который меняется его содержимое появляется "кнопочка" по клику по которой должна выполняться определенная функция, если убрать курсор из блока, содержимое меняется снова, на содержимое которое было до наведения курсора. Как реализовать? Пробовал, код выше, не получилось. Сюда и написал, может кто-то поможет реализовать выше изложение.

Comment: @AndreyVitovtov, воспроизведите проблему через запускаемый сниппет кода, JSFiddle или CodePen.

Comment: @AndreyVitovtov Хорошо, как мне воспроизвести, то, что вы написали?  Как мне тестировать то, что я вам могу попытаться предложить? В чём проблема написать пример, который можно воспроизвести? Подумайте, может именно поэтому вы не получили ответа, так как не не создали [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov,  Пожалуйста

Comment: @AndreyVitovtov А зачем вам код на `mouseenter` и `mouseleave`? Здесь же всё можно реализовать на чистом HTML/CSS (кроме `click`). А обрабочик `click` можно сделать чтобы просто брал количество звёзд нужного цвета и таким образом определял оценку.

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov В примере так, а вообще на странице будет много таких рейтингов пользователей и для каждого он будет свой. Изначально отображается количество звезд для каждого свое. Подскажите если можно...

Comment: @AndreyVitovtov Хорошо, будет время — напишу ответ.

Comment: @terron, сделал